# What is the characteristics for the wave equation with space dimension more than 1?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know that the characteristics for the 1-d space wave equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ is $x=\pm t+c$. But what is the situation for 2-d space wave equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$? Are the characteristics now hyperplanes?

Answer (score 1):

In higher spatial dimensions there are no characteristics. The information travels along to the light cone:
$$
c^2t^2=x^2+y^2.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by there are no characteristics in higher spatial dimensions? I thought we need to just find a function $\phi(t,x,y)$, s.t. $\phi_t^2=\phi_x^2+\phi_y^2$. And the set$\{\phi=const\}$ would be the family of characteristic surfaces. When I tried to solve the equation, I got planes. But my intuition tells me that it should be something like the cone you mentioned. I don't know where I went wrong.